# iOS UIStackView contraints animate Hidden

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview

I have a `UIStackView (stack1)` that contains two arranged views: a `UIStackView (stack2)` and a `UIScrollView (scroll)`

`stack2` has fixed height and both it and `scroll` have fixed width. `scroll` will take the remaining space.

With the press of a button, `stack2` will be Hidden, causing `scroll` to expand and 'move up' and with same button, `stack2` will reappear and `scroll will go back to original size

For some reason, the first animation works fine but when `stack2` is supposed to reappear, it appears behind `scroll` which still takes the whole space. Why is that? I also get some "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" warning.

Here's how they are created (this is xamarin btw but I don't think that matters)

```
var stack1 = new UIStackView(View.Frame);
stack1.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical;
stack1.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center;
stack1.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillProportionally;
stack1.Spacing = 0;

var scroll = new UIScrollView(frame);
var stack2 = new UIStackView();
stack2.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal;
stack2.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center;
stack2.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualCentering;
stack2.Spacing = 20;

... adding things in stack2 ...

scroll.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
stack2.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new []{
    stack2.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(200),
    scroll.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(frame.Height),
    scroll.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(frame.Width)
});

stack1.AddArrangedSubview(stack2);
stack1.AddArrangedSubview(scroll);
View.AddSubview(stack1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, you set the fixed width and height for the `scroll` (being equal to the `view.frame`). On the other hand, the size of the `scroll` is determined by the `stack1` (based on it's alignment, spacing, distribution properties and the position of the `scroll` in the arrangedSubviews array)

So the constraints contradict to each other. When you hide `stack2` - contradiction disappears temporarily, but it appears again when `stack2` comes back to the view.
In this situation the system must ignore some contradicting constrains (starting with constraints that have lower priority btw), so it decided to remove `stack1` arrangement to satisfy height and width constraints of the `scroll`.

Try to remove this string of code: `scroll.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(frame.Height),`
It should work.

Comment: when i remove it i get a weird behavior. `stack1` now only shows `stack2` centered, `scroll` is nowhere to be seen. when i toggle the button, `scroll` appears, takes up the whole space and `stack2` properly hides, but then i unhide `stack2`, `scroll` slides out of view again and `stack2` is back to being centered

Comment: ohhh i also changed the `FillProportionally` to `Fill` and it works :) thanks!

Comment: I'm glad my answer at least prompted you the solution :)